Linux issue with GNUTLS module, applications failing to run
Running the latest version of pop-os, I am trying to launch gnome-control-center unsuccessfully via GUI or terminal.
Via terminal I am getting the errors below:
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/libp11-kit.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-base-3.so.1)
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/libp11-kit.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgck-1.so.0)
gnome-control-center: /usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30: version `GNUTLS_3_6_10' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libcli-smb-common.so.0)

Another issue is with flatpak upgrade:
/usr/local/lib/libgnutls.so.30: version `GNUTLS_3_6_3' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
Warning: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL32.nvidia-550-67/x86_64/1.4 from remote flathub: TLS support is not available
Warning: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL32.nvidia-555-58-02/x86_64/1.4 from remote flathub: TLS support is not available
Warning: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.GL32.nvidia-560-35-03/x86_64/1.4 from remote flathub: TLS support is not available

I tried reinstalling the referenced packages, but so far I haven't made any progress, any suggestions?

/usr/local/lib/ is for system administrators to locally override normal vendor-supplied libraries - it sounds like you have installed software from outside the PopOS repositories (perhaps by compiling it from source code?) that has introduced incompatible libraries there.

@steeldriver Indeed removing the modules in that directory solved the issue, can you put this solution as an answer?
